# How to make hibernate query faster

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I am currently working on a task to improve performance of an action and the slowest part of code is this hibernate query:

```
.createQuery( "SELECT distinct p FROM CSParcel p " +
                              " WHERE p.bag.destination.loop.line.changeover.barcode = :barcode AND p.created > :limit " +
                              " AND (p.bag.destination.loop.courierLoop.id = :courierId OR p.bag.destination.loop.line.courier.id = :courierId)" +
                              " AND p.latestAction.actionType <> :doruceni" + " AND p.id NOT IN " +
                              "(SELECT pa.parcel.id " + "   FROM CSParcelAction pa " +
                              " WHERE pa.actionType = :predani AND pa.courier.id = :courierId AND pa.timestamp > :limit" +
                              ")", CSParcel.class )
                .setParameter( "barcode", changeoverBarcode.toUpperCase() )
                .setParameter( "limit", Time.setTime( 0, 0, 0, cal.getTime() ) )
                .setParameter( "courierId", courierId )
                .setParameter( "predani", CSParcelActionType.CHANGEOVER )
                .setParameter( "doruceni", CSParcelActionType.DELIVERY )
                .getResultList();
```

are there any ways to make it run faster?

Thank you for every suggestion.

Comment: Well, that depends on how "slow" it really is. Did you check the SQL that's generated (Hibernate will log the SQL query as DEBUG under `org.hibernate.SQL`)? If not then you can take that query and directly execute it against your database (you'd need to add the parameters though) and add the `explain` command to let the database tell you how that query is executed. This should provide some hints on where you could improve it, e.g. by adding some indices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Thomas , this query can take from 20sec. to 40sec. for almost 600 entities. I was adviced to use joins instead of subqueries. I think that going through so many parameters `p.bag.destination.loop.line.changeover.barcode = :barcode` is slowing this down. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Well, `p.bag.destination.loop.line.changeover.barcode` would probably result in at least 5 joins but those seem to be to-one relations or otherwise Hibernate would complain. It's hard to tell what exactly is slowing down the query without knowing much more hence my suggestion to use `explain` on the resulting SQL query.

Comment: A few suggestions though: 1) check how many results you'd get without the `distinct` - we had a case where a couple of joins resulted in 1 million rows being returned for _one_ (!) distinct entity. 2) check whether there are any sequential scans that could be sped up with an index 3) instead of the `not in <subquery>` try `not exists <subquery>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor with some tools and you will see how queries behave, normally adding some indices where is needed is enough, if you databases alredy have indices you can do some kind of maintenance to tables you use.
Here is some information

[enter link description here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0001138.html)